# Schauder basis in the space of convergent sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Could someone help me to prove that {$e_k$ : $k\geq{0}$ } (where $e_k$ (if $k>0$) is the sequence with $1$ in the place $k$ and $0$ in the rest of sequence  and $e_0 $ is the constant sequence equal to $1$) is  a Schauder basis of sequences which converge?.

Thanks.

Comment: What norm are you considering on this space? Is it $\|x \| = \sup_n \lvert x_n \rvert$? And don't you mean the space of convergent sequences?

Comment: Yes, I have just edited it. The exercise dont't specificate the norm that wehave to use, so I supposse that we can choose the norm $||·||_\infty$

Answer (score 2):

Consider any converging sequence $x$ with limit $c = \lim_n x_n$. 
Now consider the following sequence of sequences
$$
a_n = c e_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-c)e_i.
$$
Notice that $x-a_n = (0,0, \ldots, 0, x_{n+1}-c, x_{n+2}-c, \ldots)$ or in other words $\|x-a_n \| = \sup_{m \geq n+1} \lvert x_m -c \rvert$. So $$
\lim_n \| x- a_n \| = \limsup_n \lvert x_n -c \rvert = 0.
$$
So these vectors will indeed form a Schauder basis.

Comment: And how can we conclude that $a_n$ is unique?

Comment: @mathlife That isn't too hard to prove. For example first assume the first term stays the same, (i.e. $ce_0$). It's easy to see that the other coefficients must remain the same as well. Then assume the first term differs (i.e. $d e_0$ with $d \neq c$), then the sum won't converge.